# A Potential Euler-Lagrange Equation Alternate Derivation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, action, geodesics, variational-calculus

Can the Euler Lagrange Equation be derived with this overall strategy?

Step 1 – Define a geodesic in flat space to be $\frac{d}{dy} \frac{ds}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{ds}{dy}$, where $ds$ represents the infinitesimal arc length of the curve.

Step 2 – For non-flat space, some of the terms in one side of the equation we just defined must be changed in order to preserve the geodesic properties.  $dx$ is not the same everywhere, so if we want to compare the $ds$’s and $dy$’s at one $dx$ with the $ds$’s and $dy$’s at another $dx$, and say that they’re still equivalent, we need to make some adjustments.    $(ds)$ on one side of the equation must become $(\frac{d}{dx} ds)$ and $(dy)$ must become $(\frac{d}{dx} dy)$ since the $dx$’s are no longer uniform everywhere.

So the equation we started with now becomes $\frac{d}{dy} \frac{ds}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\frac{d}{dx} ds}{\frac{d}{dx} dy}\right)$.

Hopefully, this is equivalent to $\frac{d}{dy} \frac{ds}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d \left(\frac{ds}{dx}\right)}{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}\right)$, but I'm not sure how to formally show that.

Assuming we can properly continue, $\frac{ds}{dx}$ is equal to the Lagrangian, $L$.  So the equation of a geodesic in nonflat space can now be represented as $\frac{dL}{dy} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{dL}{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}\right)$, which is the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Is this derivation valid, or does the general strategy at least fly?  Does it have any major errors that ruin everything?  Or just small errors that can be cleaned up?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost.  I don't know what $x$ or $y$ are (coordinates in a plane?), what it means to take two total derivatives in a row (surely for a curve, the arc length depends on only one parameter?), how your first point relates to a geodesic, how you can arbitrarily decide to replace $ds$ with $\frac{d}{dx}ds$, or how you decided that $\frac{ds}{dx}$ should be a Lagrangian of some kind. The last point makes sense if you're restricting your attention to calculating geodesics, but I'm still not following the rest.

Comment: J. Murray, the x and y are coordinates of a coordinate system drawn on a warped plane.  In a warped plane, each dx and dy are not necessarily equal.  If you're comparing a ds at one of the dx's with the ds at another, the d/dx of ds is an attempt to modify one of the ds's to compare it with the other.  I probably should have used subscripts or something, but I'm not great with notation. In most derivations, I believe what I use as S is usually represented by J, And DJ/dx in those derivations should be the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret OP's question (v3) as essentially asking the following.

> Is
>   $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}
> ~=~ \frac{\partial}{\partial q^j}\frac{dS}{dt}
> ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial S}{\partial q^j}
> ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\frac{dS}{dt}}{\frac{dq^j}{dt}}\right)
> ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\frac{L}{\dot{q}^j}
> ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}$$
>   a mathematically correct derivation of [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)?

The short answer is: *No,* it's not. For starters, the last equality is obviously incorrect.

Comment: I am saying $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}~=~\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\frac{dS}{dt}}{d\frac{dq}{dt}}\right) ~=~~\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\frac{d}{dt}ds}{\frac{d}{dt}dq}\right)$$
I am not mentioning $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{L}{\dot{q}^j} ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}$$ anywhere that I can see.

Comment: I also want to mention that I know $d\frac{ds}{dt}$ does not equal $\frac{d}{dt}ds$ but I still think $$\left(\frac{d\frac{ds}{dt}}{d\frac{dq}{dt}}\right) ~=~\left(\frac{\frac{d}{dt}ds}{\frac{d}{dt}dq}\right)$$